# How to rust curl as a nested command in rust?

Tags: bash, rust

I currently have a shell script in a website. I'm creating an application in Rust that executes the bash script.

The solution i have right now is to download the file locally, and then actually run the script:

```rust
  let url = "http://example.com/myscript.sh";
  let file = "homebrew_install.sh";

  // Send an HTTP GET request to the URL
  let mut response = reqwest::blocking::get(url)?;

  // Create a new file to write the downloaded image to
  let mut file = File::create(file_name)?;

  // Copy the contents of the response to the file
  copy(&mut response, &mut file)?;


  // Install from the SH file.
  let path = Path::new("./").join(file);
  let status = Command::new("/bin/bash")
    .arg(path.as_os_str())
    .spawn();
```

However, I'd like to be able to do it on a single command that doesn't bother with the download part since it means i also have to keep track of file to delete.

Ideally, i'd like to run something like this:

```rust
let status = Command::new("/bin/bash")
    .arg("-c")
    .arg("\"$(curl -fsSL http://example.com/myscript.sh)\"")
    .spawn();
```

But as of right now, this essentially prints out the script to the screen rather than actually run the sh.

Comment: Try omitting the escaped quotes. You need them to escape the argument from your shell, but `Command` isn't a shell.

Comment: If i remove the quotes, i get the following: 
`/bin/bash: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The way you've put it I think you need 2 instances of `bash` one to run the `curl` and another to run the returned script.

Comment: Why not do it as `.arg("curl -fsSL … | bash")` as would be usual from a shell? Also, if possible, it's better not to assume that `bash` is at `/bin/bash`, you can just use `Command::new("bash")` and it find it from the correct path. Extending, I'd probably use `reqwest` over `curl`, no need to worry whether it's installed. Short example: `Command::new("bash").stdin(Stdio::piped()).spawn()?.stdin.take().unwrap().write_all(&reqwest::blocking::get("http://example.com/myscript.sh")?.bytes()?)`. Lastly: https?

Comment: Instead of fiddling around with `bash -c ...`, I would write a standalone bash script, make it executable, and then run it from within `rust`. It will also be easier to debug.